# SSD Mobilenetv2 object detection inference

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, inference, mobilenet

I trained a Tensorflow SSD Mobilenet v2 object detector and I want to make preditcions on my test images with bounding boxes. Can someone show me an example for the inference?

Answer (score -1):

This might comes as too late but [here](https://blog.roboflow.com/training-a-tensorflow-object-detection-model-with-a-custom-dataset/) is a great tutorial on the subject that includes inference

I'm not sure which implementation you went with, but here they are using `tensorflow-object-detection` repo, so you might need to fork it if not already.
Also, there is a [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1wTMIrJhYsQdq_u7ROOkf0Lu_fsX5Mu8a) for the entire, training, inference, and downloading the best model `.pb file

Hope this helps

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)